# Keeping ClutterActor at the lowest level

Tags: clutter, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I am working on a Gnome shell extension. I have an actor which I add on uiGroup as

```
Main.uiGroup.add_actor( my_actor );
```

I also tried

```
Main.layoutManager.addChrome( my_actor );
```

as well with many options.

How can I get it sticked to the most back on window stack?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways of doing that and it seems impossible. Instead, I developed an application called keep_below() method in GTK.